# Unable to extract the username of a linkedin through through Selector and chromedriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
from parsel import Selector
driver.get('https://uk.linkedin.com/in/pauljgarner')
driver.page_source
sel = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
name = sel.xpath('//*[starts-with(@class, "pv-top-card--list.inline-flex.align-items-center")]/text()').extract_first()
```

I am supposed to get the full name of the user but for some reason it is not working. So this is what it actually gives -

```
In[1]: sel
out[1]: <Selector xpath=None data='<html lang="en" class="artdeco window...'>
```

So nothing inside XPath, what am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this locator:

```
XPath: //li[@class = 'inline t-24 t-black t-normal break-words']
CSS: .break-words
```

It successfully return `Paul Garner`

Comment: So I wrote 'sel.xpath('//li[@class = 'inline t-24 t-black t-normal break-words']')' which is showing syntax error and then I wrote 'sel.xpath('//li[@class = 'inline.t-24.t-black.t-normal.break-words']')' which is also showing syntax error. Sorry I am a beginner in web scraping so this may sound dumb :(

Answer (score 0):

I ran in the same problem, below line helped me get through this:

```
(normalize-space(//li[@class="inline t-24 t-black t-normal break-words"]))
```